# "the_title" changes the menu items also

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'make_custom_title', 10, 2);
function make_custom_title {
    return "MyTitle";
}
```

- I am using the theme : https://wordpress.org/themes/greentech-lite/

[I want to change MyTitle(both) which is infront of the blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbCzZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `if` block here.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'make_custom_title', 10, 2);
function make_custom_title( $title, $id ) {
    global $post;

    if( $post->ID == $id ) {
        return 'MyTitle';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Will this not fail when `Page-Title` and `Menu-Title` will have same `Post-ID`?
- Menu title will also change.